# python iterating on multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have

`file_2000.dta`, `file_2001.dta`, `file_2002.dta` and so on.

I also have

`file1_2000.dta`, `file1_2001.dta`, `file1_2002.dta` and so on.

I want to iterate on the file year.

```
Let (year) = 2000, 2001, 2002, etc

import file_(year) using pandas. 
import file1_(year) using pandas. 

file_(year)['name'] = file_(year).index
file1_(year)['name'] = file1_(year).index2

merged = pd.merge(file_(year), file1_(year), on='name') 

write/export merged_(year).dta
```

Comment: it is not really clear to me what you want to achieve

Comment: I've edited to add some simplified code

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know there is not 'Let' keyword in Python. To iterate over multiple files in a directory you can simply use for loop with os module like the following:

```
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\admin'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.startswith("file_200") and filename.endswith(".dat"):
        # do something
    else:
        continue
```

> Another approach is to use regex to tell python the files names to match during the iteration. the pattern should be: pattern = r"file_20\d+"

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to use the  [read_stata function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_stata.html), based on your .dta extensions, to read the files in a loop, create a list of the separate dataframes to be able to work with them separately, and then [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat) all dataframes into one.

Something like:

```
list_of_files = ['file_2000.dta', 'file_2001.dta', 'file_2002.dta']  # full paths here...

frames = []

for f in list_of_files:
    df = pd.read_stata(f)
    frames.append(df)

consolidated_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

These questions might be relevant to your case:

[How to Read multiple files in Python for Pandas separate dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766821/how-to-read-multiple-files-in-python-for-pandas-separate-dataframes)

[Pandas read_stata() with large .dta files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744527/pandas-read-stata-with-large-dta-files)